# my rspec test won't pass: Michael Hartl's rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, rspec

I am at the end of chapter five doing the exercises. I am supposed to be testing that the links go to the correct pages. Here is my test code.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "LayoutLinks" do

    it "should have the right links on the layout" do
        visit root_path
        click_link "About"
        response.should have_selector('title', :content => "About")
        click_link "Home"
        response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Home")
        click_link "Help"
        response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Help")
        click_link "Contact"
        response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Contact")
        click_link "Sign up now!"
        response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Sign up")
        end
        end
```

Everything passes except for the last test. It says that it can not find a link with the text "Sign up now!" . I know that the page does have a "Sign up now!" link. I thought that maybe it rendered differently in the source code, but when I look at the source code it looks normal `<a href="/signup" class="signup_button round">Sign up now!</a>` . From my understanding, it is supposed to click on the links and then test if the title matches the :content symbol. Am I misunderstanding something?

here is the error I am getting:

```
Failures:

  1) LayoutLinks should have the right links on the layout
     Failure/Error: click_link "Sign up now!"
     Webrat::NotFoundError:
       Could not find link with text or title or id "Sign up now!"
```

Comment: I also tried setting :content => "Sign up now!" just to experiment, but the problem seems to be finding the link on the root_path and not at the response.

Comment: long shot but does it work if you remove the exclamation mark. `click_link "Sign up now"`

Comment: Just tried that. It gives me the same error. I also tried taking the ! out of the link.

Comment: FWIW, one of the few things I don't like about that tutorial is the reliance on controller specs. Cucumber stories work much better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the "Sign up now!" link is in fact not on all pages, and this test actually navigates the pages.

At least in the version of this tutorial that I ran through some time ago, that link was only on the home page.

If you add a `visit root_path` just before that last `click_link` it'll likely work.

A better test would have that check in an independent test related specifically to the home page.

Comment: awesome! I went ahead and did an independent test. I didn't realize it was testing for all the pages. I thought that because I put visit root_path that it was only testing links exclusively on the home page.

Comment: I got hung up here too and you provided the answer, @DonRoby.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also, the title text is `"Sign Up"`.  Capital 'U'.

The line needs to be:

```
response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Sign Up")
```

The prior answer's advice to do a `visit root_path` is unneeded if the page visited just before this one is `"Home"`

Comment: Just to clarify Marc's statement--- the click_link function actually, you know, *navigates to that page.* Rspec isn't testing *all* the pages, just the one it happens to be visiting @ the moment. If that happens to be "Home," as Marc points out, the "Sign up now!" link will be available.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the test will not work is because you need to run:

```
$ rake db:test:prepare
```

At least, that was why my tests were not passing.

I found the solution [in this forum](http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa;jsessionid=Nr47ThgJOx6HgbED?messageID=102033&#102033)